# Стилизовать input с эффектом выдавливания в соответствии с макетом CSS

Tags: css, input, box-shadow

На макете поля input оформлены следующим образом:
[image: Рисунок 1]

Третий день играю с box-shadow inset, не могу подобрать нужные значения чтобы повторить макет. Помогите, пожалуйста стилизовать input.

Comment: где вы увидели эти инпуты?

Comment: Старый макет Safari tour от 2013 года. Прикрепить?

Comment: Да, прикрепите, если можно.

Comment: Интересно, а можно получить psd макет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: #1480a7;
}

input, textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #0f6586;
  color: #fff;
  font: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 
    5px 5px 10px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.35) inset,
    3px  3px 1px -2px #005775 inset,
    -3px 3px 1px -2px #005775 inset,
    3px  -3px 1px -2px #6dc2e7 inset,
    -3px -3px 1px -2px #6dc2e7 inset;
}

input:not(:last-child), textarea:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Name"><br>
<input type="email" placeholder="email address"><br>
<input type="tel" placeholder="phone"><br>
<textarea type="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
```

Comment: Господа, я уже перешагнул за 30 лет, но единственное, что вертится на языке: Вы волшебники! У меня в голове не укладывается, как Вам удалось подобрать пять теней, которые в совокупности дают нужный эффект? Это натренированный профессиональный взгляд или есть какие-то инструменты?

Comment: Спасибо. Просто небольшой навык, т.к. пытался написать инструмент для работы с тенями (`box-shadow`).. А вот насчёт инструментов подобных я не в курсе)

Comment: Я, во-первых, не знал про возможность использования нескольких теней на одном элементе. Но даже если бы и знал, мне кажется, я и за неделю не подобрал бы нужные значения) Спасибо! Могу я сделать что-то еще в благодарность, кроме плюса Вашему ответу?

Comment: Не за что. Ничего, этого достаточно)

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю Вы хотите воспроизвести Emboss эффект:

```css
input {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  color: #333;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
    0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input:focus { 
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
    0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    0 0 5px 1px #51CBEE;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Введите текст">
```

Comment: Спасибо! Да, именно то, что надо. Как у Вас получается получать нужную комбинацию трех теней: натренированный глаз или существуют специальные инструменты для этого?

Comment: @ Alex Помогает дизайнерский опыт и гугл по названию требуемого эффекта. Дальше просто подстройка относительно нужного результата

Comment: Да все равно в голове не укладывается, как можно на глаз подобрать значения теней, чтобы в результате они совместно давали такой эффект. Не знал, что эффект называется Emboss. Иначе бы вначале погуглил по названию)  Спасибо! Могу я сделать что-то еще в благодарность, кроме плюса Вашему ответу?